# 3-cycles of the iterated quadratic maps and the Galois Theory of $x^3 = a(x-1)$

Tags: galois-theory, dynamical-systems

Taken from these notes [[1](http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/galoistheory/cubicquartic.pdf)] on Galois Theory, I would like to show that iterating the map

$$p: x \mapsto x^2 - x - 2 $$

has a cycle of order 3 when you start with the root of $x^3 - 3x - 1 = 0$.

It would be interesting to find more cycles.  Here it is interesting the degree 8 polynomial $(p\circ p \circ p)(x) =x$ has a cubic factor.

Wolfram Alpha [[2](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28%28%28%28%28x%5E2+-+x+-+2%29%29%5E2+-+%28%28x%5E2+-+x+-+2%29%29+-+2%29%29%5E2+-+%28%28%28%28x%5E2+-+x+-+2%29%29%5E2+-+%28%28x%5E2+-+x+-+2%29%29+-+2%29%29+-+2%29-x)] says  it factors into two cubics and a quadratic:

$$(p\circ p \circ p)(x) - x = (x^3 - 3x - 1 )(x^2 - 2x - 2)(x^3 -2x^2 -3x +  5) $$

---

In those same notes, we learn the polynomial $x^3 - a(x-1) = 0$ also has Galois group $A_3 = C_3$ when $a = k^2 + k + 7$.  What is the quadratic substitution that generates it?

Comment: Well, that factorization is exactly what gives you the result that you need - is it not?  Your second question seems quite separate. Perhaps it should be a separate question?